# MSBTE Model Answer Paper Diploma, has been removed from Google Play due to a policy violation

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

**Issue: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information. We’ve identified that your app collects and transmits the Android advertising identifier, which is subject to a privacy policy requirement. If your app collects the Android advertising ID, you must provide a valid privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Console, and from within the app**

Google mail me this message and removed my app from the play store now i don't known what i can do.

Comment: This sort of question is best asked not on StackOverflow. Instead you should ask Google Play support, using the help menu on the Play Console. But there are also lots of other similar questions on StackOverflow. I'll suggest marking this as a duplicate of one of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I show privacy policy in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538592/how-do-i-show-privacy-policy-in-my-application)