# How do I show privacy policy in my application

Tags: android, google-play, google-advertising-id

My app has been removed due to violating the Android Advertising ID. So I requested an appeal to get my app into the app store and this is what they respond.

> There are three ways to address this issue:
>
> 1. If your app requests user data or makes sensitive permissions
>      requests such as Phone, Accounts, Contacts, Camera, Microphone, or **if    your app uses the Android advertising identifier, you'll need
>      to add    a valid privacy policy in two places: your app's store
>      listing page    (instructions below) and within your app.**
> 2. As a second option, you can    remove any requests for user data or
>          sensitive permissions such as    Android Advertising identifier. You
>          will not need to add a privacy    policy if you remove these
>          requests.
> 3. If you cannot complete steps 1    or 2, you'll need to
>      unpublish the app from Google Play. If your app    is already
>          unpublished, you don’t need to take action unless you    re-publish
>          the app in the future.

**I recently just add a valid privacy policy in my app's store listing page and my app was published into the Google Play store again.**

However, I don't know how to put it within my app. I have searched all over the place on how to do it and I can't find anyway to do it. They only show me on how to add privacy policy into the app's store listing page which I already did.

I don't want to risk getting removed again.

Comment: Add a menu item called privacy policy and show a new page on its click,

Comment: Following might also help https://medium.com/@swarooptvm/how-to-fix-advertising-id-policy-violation-in-google-play-store-6d9cf92d335d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are sites that help you write a privacy policy for your app (privacy policy generators), for example:
https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/.

The file you get in the end you can upload to a website, if you have one, or even to dropbox (with permission to everyone to read), and add a link in your app to this file. You can also do it with a webview or any other way to present text in the app.